# EXCEL VBA for permutation and combinations calculations

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, compare, dropdown

I am completely new to Excel VBA, and I'm trying to write code to do a simple task.

There are 3 Worksheets in an Excel:  `Summary`, `Discount`, `Price`

Worksheet `Summary` contains data as below:

[image: img]

**Dropdown** (Data in `B1` and `B3`):

```
Type: Supermarket,Hopcoms
Product:Dairy,Meat,Combo
Category:Chicken,Eggs,Eggs+Chicken
```

Worksheet `Discount` contains data as below:

[image]

Worksheet `Price` contains data as below:

[image: img]

**Tasks:**

1. User in Summary Sheet selects Data in `B1:B3` through drop down list.
2. Based on the selection , Discount in % should be selected for corresponding combination from Discount Sheet
   For Ex : If user selects Supermarket-Combo-Eggs+Chicken in Summary Sheet(from #1) , total discount availed should be 13%(as per Discount Sheet).
3. User navigates to Price sheet and enters data in Total Price column for each customer
4. When User clicks **Calculate Discount** button now 13% discount should be applied on Total Price for all customer and discount amount should be updated in Discount Availed column
5. Total Discount price provided to all customers should be updated next to T.Discount.

Apologies for any mistakes, could anyone please resolve this?
Please let me know for any questions

Comment: Questions which are just a set of specifications, with no code, and no specific problem description (being new to VBA does not fit that requirement) tend to get closed here.  You can help your chances of getting help by describing what *specifically* is preventing you from implementing this.

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg  for the edits. I am facing trouble in using for loop  and to provide if and statements for the all PnC for the above. As i haven't made much progress, hence not posting any code.

Comment: I think applying the discount by replacing the existing price is not the best approach.  I am working to a code solution and I will insert a 'Price' column, where the user set price will remain and in the next two columns the 'Total Price' and 'Discount'... Would it be OK in this way?

Comment: Yes @FaneDuru , that would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the next code, please. But before that, please insert another column in `Price` worksheet, between existing "Customer" (B:B) and "Total Price" (C:C) and name  it "Price". There the user will fill the standard price (without any discount) and in "Total Price" the the price will be calculated applying the discount:

```
Sub TestApplyDiscount()
 Dim shS As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet, shP As Worksheet, lastRowP As Long
 Dim strType As String, strProd As String, strCat As String, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim rowType As Long, rowProd As Long, rowCat As Long, disc As Double
 
 Set shS = Worksheets("Summary")
 Set shD = Worksheets("Discount")
 Set shP = Worksheets("Price")
 lastRowP = shP.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 strType = shS.Range("B1").value
 strProd = shS.Range("B2").value
 strCat = shS.Range("B3").value
 
 With WorksheetFunction
       rowType = .Match(strType, shD.Range("A1:A19"), 0)

        rowProd = .Match(strProd, shD.Range("B" & rowType & ":B" & rowType + 8), 0)
        rowProd = rowProd + rowType - 1
        
         rowCat = .Match(strCat, shD.Range("C" & rowProd & ":C" & rowProd + 3), 0)
         rowCat = rowCat + rowProd - 1
         
         disc = shD.Range("D" & rowCat).value
 End With
 For i = 2 To lastRowP
    shP.Range("E" & i).value = disc & "%"
    shP.Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-(RC[-1]*RC[1])"
 Next i
End Sub
```

I am waiting for some feedback...